# Timer used for WPF display with strange behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I made a panel with several buttons in WPF. 
When mouse enter in some button, new buttons appear and will disappear 1000 ms after mouse leave.

But I have a strange behavior: 1000 ms in some case become shorter and shorter after each use.

Timer event

```
private void TimerEventProcessorForButtonA(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    _myTimerForButtonA.Stop(); 
    miniButton1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void TimerEventProcessorForButtonB(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    _myTimerForButtonB.Stop(); 
    miniButton2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

WaitTime functions calling timer:

```
public void WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton1(int givenTime)
{
    _myTimerForButtonA = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    _myTimerButtonA.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessorForForButtonA);
    _myTimerForForButtonA.Interval = givenTime;
    _myTimerForForButtonA.Start();
}

public void WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton2(int givenTime)
{
    _myTimerForButtonB = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    _myTimerForButtonB.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessorForForButtonB);
    _myTimerForForButtonB.Interval = givenTime;
    _myTimerForForButtonB.Start();
}
```

Event when leave button:

```
private void buttonA_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Border button = sender as Border;
    button.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(_colorOut);
    WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton1(1000); // hide minibuttons
}

private void buttonB_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Border button = sender as Border;
    button.Background = (SolidColorBrush) new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(_colorOut);
    WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton2(1000);
}
```

As described in code, I have buttonA and buttonB. When I enter buttonA, miniButton1 appear - it will disappear 1000 ms after mouse leave event.
Same thing for buttonB that reveal miniButton2.

If I only enter and leave buttonB everything is correct. Same as ButtonA.
**The problem:** If I enter/leave buttonA and B, then, these 1000ms go shorter and shorter. Disappearance of miniButton also appear before I leave buttonA and B. also happen before I leave the button.

Eveything behave like if timers were confusing each other.
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: The class `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` implements `IDisposable`. Are you disposing each previous instance before creating a new one? Not doing so could cause your issue. Can you try and see if that solves the problem?

Comment: Crystal ball application required.  You got into trouble by re-creating the Timer objects repeatedly.  Bad idea in more than one way, what you are complaining about is that the previous timer object is still merrily ticking away so is making the button disappear too soon.  Worse, it never stops since you can't call its Stop() method anymore.  Only create the Timer objects once, in the constructor of the window.  Use the Closed event to dispose them.  And have a look at DispatcherTimer.

Comment: Do not use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in a WPF application. Use `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` instead. No need to dispose of a DispatcherTimer. And as said, create timer instances only once. Then start and stop an existing timer repeatedly.

Comment: As mentioned I created timer 1 time and just use stop and start and it works. @Clemens : why System.Windows.Forms.Timer shall not be used in WPF (indeed it is not a winform but which problem does it trigger) ?

Comment: Please read the Remarks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're recreating a new `Timer` every time a `MouseLeave` event is fired, if you happen to fire that event twice within 1000ms, you'll be recreating a new `Timer` before the `Tick` event of the previous `Timer` execute, which will make the previous `Timer` run indefinitely.

Here's what's happening when you fire `MouseLeave` event twice within 1000ms :

```
1) MouseLeave: _myTimerForButtonA is assigned a new Timer instance (ie: Timer1), Tick event registered.
2) MouseLeave: _myTimerForButtonA is assigned a new Timer instance (ie: Timer2), Tick event registered.
3) Timer1.Tick event fires TimerEventProcessorForButtonA, whichs stops _myTimerForButtonA which points to Timer2.
4) Timer2.Tick event fires TimerEventProcessorForButtonA, whichs stops _myTimerForButtonA which points to Timer2 (and is already stopped).
5) Timer1.Tick event fires TimerEventProcessorForButtonA indefinitely, because Timer1 is not referenced anymore and no one will ever call `Stop` on it.
```

I was able to fix your code by stopping the timer on `MouseEnter` event

```
    private void TimerEventProcessorForButtonA(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TimerEventProcessorForButtonA");
        _myTimerForButtonA.Stop();
        _myTimerForButtonA.Dispose();
        miniButton1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void TimerEventProcessorForButtonB(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("** TimerEventProcessorForButtonB");
        _myTimerForButtonB.Stop();
        _myTimerForButtonB.Dispose();
        miniButton2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public void WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton1(int givenTime)
    {
        _myTimerForButtonA = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _myTimerForButtonA.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessorForButtonA);
        _myTimerForButtonA.Interval = givenTime;
        _myTimerForButtonA.Start();
    }

    public void WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton2(int givenTime)
    {
        _myTimerForButtonB = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        _myTimerForButtonB.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessorForButtonB);
        _myTimerForButtonB.Interval = givenTime;
        _myTimerForButtonB.Start();
    }

    private void buttonA_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Border button = sender as Border;
        button.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(_colorOut);
        WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton1(1000); // hide minibuttons
    }

    private void buttonB_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Border button = sender as Border;
        button.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(_colorOut);
        WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton2(1000);
    }

    private void buttonA_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_myTimerForButtonA?.Enabled == true)
            _myTimerForButtonA.Stop();
        miniButton1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void buttonB_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_myTimerForButtonB?.Enabled == true)
            _myTimerForButtonB.Stop();
        miniButton2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

As stated in comments of your post, you shouldn't create a new `Timer` each time, and you should dispose it once you're done. Also, referencing Forms in a WPF project is a bad idea unless really necessary, which rarely is. You'll probably want to read about [Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview) for UI animation.

Answer (score 0):

So basically this happens on mouse leave:

```
creating the timer
starting the timer
```

And this happens when timer expires:

```
stopping the timer
```

So if mouse repeatedly enters and leaves a button, it keeps creating and starting new timers. Which causes more than one timer to be running at the same time.

```
public void WaitThisTimeAndHideMiniButton1(int givenTime)
{
    if(_myTimerForButtonA != null && _myTimerForButtonA.Enabled)
    {
         _myTimerForButtonA.Stop();
    }
    _myTimerForButtonA = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    _myTimerButtonA.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessorForForButtonA);
    _myTimerForForButtonA.Interval = givenTime;
    _myTimerForForButtonA.Start();
}
```

Although there are more issues here as mentioned in comments, this should fix that problem.